# How to skip displaying some content based on the element present on the page or not using javascript or react?

Tags: javascript

I have to display content for four elements on page. If the element is present on the page then i display content for it. if not skip showing content for that element that is not present and move on to show content for next element on the page.

To explain further, consider i have four elements namely title (div element), menu (svg element), map (image element), settings (header h4 element).

Among these elements only map and settings elements will not be visible sometimes.

and i put these in a  variable array of objects defined as below,

```js
const data = [{
    id: '2',
    val: 'value1',
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    val: 'value2',
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    val: 'value3',
    element: '.some_class image',
  }
  {
    id: '5',
    val: 'value3',
    element: '.class2 h4',
  }
]
```

the content for these elements in displayed in a div with previous and next arrows.

when i click the start button on the page, the content for the elements start to display and clicking next button takes me to content for next button in this case title and clicking next button takes me to menu then to settings and finally to settings.

Similarly clicking prev button takes me to the content from last to first.

below are the methods to handle those,

```
this.state.count is undefined initially.

handle_start = () => {
    this.setState({count: 0});
}

handle_next = () => {
    const next = this.state.count + 1 >= data.length ? 0 : this.state.count 
    + 1;
    this.setState({count: next});
}

handle_previous = () => {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count - 1});
}
```

Now how can i skip showing content for the elements map and settings based on element present or not?

How can i do it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: please double check your condition `document.querySelector(data[i].element !== null)` may be you want something like this instead `document.querySelector(data[i].element) !== null`

Comment: thanks. there was  a typo edited it.

Comment: shouldnt it be `!=`, not   `!==`

Comment: `document.querySelector(data[i].element !== null)` is not right. This will evaluate to `document.querySelector(true)` or `document.querySelector(false)`.

Comment: I suppose you need `data[i].element && !document.querySelector(data[i].element))` based on your description

Comment: true works..thanks. but this doesnt look a nice idea..okay shall update my question.